# Using wildcard attribute in css selector does not return any matches

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

I want to use the following CSS selector to find HTML elements when running puppeteer.

Code:

```
let items = await page.$$eval('a.a-link-normal[href~="/product/"] > img', nodes => nodes.map(n => { ... }));
```

It does not return anything. When I remove the `"`, it says that it's not valid.
When I try the selector on https://try.jsoup.org/, it works just fine.

When I run a slightly modified code using regex, it works as well:

```
let items = await page.$$eval('a.a-link-normal > img', nodes => 
  nodes.map(n => { 
   console.log(n.href.match(/product/)) // returns something
   ...
  })
);
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Sample HTML code to check:

```
<td class="productRowColumn">
  <a class="a-link-normal" href="/product/testprod/asc/">
    <img alt="" src="sampleimg.jpg" aria-hidden="true" height="28" width="45" title="sampleProductTitle">
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question,

You should switch `[href~="/product/"]`
for `[href^="/product/"]` or `[href*="/product/"]`

`~=` being **contains word** (Not what you require) .
`^=` being **starts with**.
`*=` being **contains substring**.

Resulting in your css selector looking like this:

```
'a.a-link-normal[href^="/product/"] > img'
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute selector `~=` syntax denotes an attribute with that *word* in the property. The word must be whitespace-separated, so your code would work on something like:

```html
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/product/ testprod/asc/">
```

But not without the spaces.
The selector you want is `*=` or `^=`. As described [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax):

> `[attr*=value]`
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.
>
> `[attr^=value]`
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.